# Writing subscribed messages from MQTT to InfluxDB at the same timing

Tags: python, mqtt, influxdb

I am a beginner at influxdb, python, and using mqtt. I've succeeded to subscribe on multiple topics and send it on influxdb locally. But it appears to have approximately 0.1 second delay between those messages on the influxDB timestamps. I've tried to add "time" variable at the JSON body, it succeeded to eliminate the delay, but somehow I cannot graph it on Chronograf nor Grafana, showing "Your query or command is syntactically correct but returned no results". I also tried to use thread function to call the on_message_voltage and on_message_current at the same timing, but it didn't work. So is there any chance I'm able to send subscribed messages from MQTT to influxDB at the same timing?

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import datetime
import threading
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("Connected to MQTT my-org.org.id")
        print("Starting to receive message")
    client.subscribe("IoT_Sensor/1",qos=1)
    client.subscribe("IoT_Sensor/2",qos=2)

def on_message_voltage(client, userdata, message):  
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    json_body= [
    {
        "measurement": "Solar",
            "tags": {
                "host": "Sensor_1",
                            },
                    # "time": int(time.time()),
                            "fields": {
                                "Voltage": float(message.payload),
        }
    }
    ]
    influx_client.write_points(json_body)
    print("Voltage: " + message.topic + " " + str(message.qos) + " " + str(message.payload.decode('utf-8')))
    
def on_message_current(client, userdata, message):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "Solar",
            "tags": {
                "host": "Sensor_1",
                    },
                  # "time": int(time.time()),
                        "fields": {
                            "Current": float(message.payload),
     }
        
    }
    ]
    
    influx_client.write_points(json_body)
    print("Current: " + message.topic + " " + str(message.qos) + " " + str(message.payload.decode('utf-8')))

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print(message.topic + " " + str(message.qos) + " " + str(message.payload))

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
influx_client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, database='mqtt_test2')

def on_topic_1():
    mqttc.message_callback_add("IoT_Sensor/1", on_message_voltage)
def on_topic_2():
    mqttc.message_callback_add("IoT_Sensor/2", on_message_current)
    
try :
    threading.Thread(target=on_topic_1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=on_topic_2).start()
    mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
    mqttc.on_message = on_message
    mqttc.connect("my-org.or.id",1883,60)
    mqttc.loop_forever()
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting loop")
```

Comment: You should ask a separate question about why your Grafana/Chronograf queries is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your threading code is meaningless, just starting a new thread to run the `message_callback_add()` won't do anything useful. It just starts a thread which will add the callback then exit immediately.

You need to remove the following lines:

```
def on_topic_1():
    mqttc.message_callback_add("IoT_Sensor/1", on_message_voltage)
def on_topic_2():
    mqttc.message_callback_add("IoT_Sensor/2", on_message_current)

...

threading.Thread(target=on_topic_1).start()
threading.Thread(target=on_topic_2).start()
```

If you want to run the separate callbacks for different topics you should just add the `mqttc.message_callback_add()` calls to before the `mqttc.connect()` call.

As to why it's adding latency without a lot more information about what the whole system looks like also exactly how are you measuring the latency, have you measured how long each of the message callbacks takes to run?

Comment: I measured the latency for each messages from the timestamps given on the influxdb.I use esp32 as the publishing client that publish the messages from the sensor,  and measured the latency for publishing messages from the esp32 through the serial monitor on arduino IDE that shows zero latency. I'm not exactly sure how to measure the duration for the message callbacks to run, can you give suggestion on the python code?